# Transpose Rows to Columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that follows the following pattern:

```
q1  score
q2  score
...
q32 score
q1  score
q2  score
```

And so forth. The csv file represents the results of a survey done for different instructors

I want to make those 32 questions my features and the score my rows. However, since the 32 questions repeat for each product, a transpose didn't work for me

I tried using pd.pivot as suggested in other questions. This is as far as I get

```
courseFeedback = pd.melt(courseFeedback, id_vars = [0], var_name = [1])
courseFeedback = courseFeedback.pivot(index = [0], columns =[1])
courseFeedback.head()
```

Executing that code results in an exception:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 138632 rows, received array of length 1
```

My expected result is a dataframe like this:

```
q1    q2    q3    ... q32
score score score ... score
score score score ... score
```

Notes: 
- I'm a beginner.
- Pardon my English. I'm not a native speaker

**Edit**

Using pd.melt() I get the following result

```
   0  variable  value 
0 q1     1        1
1 q2     1        1
2 q3     1        1
```

The scores are floating points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
final=df.assign(k=df.groupby(0).cumcount()).set_index([0,'k']).unstack(0)
final.columns=final.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

---

```
0     q1     q2    q32
k                     
0  score  score  score
1  score  score    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There is one problem though. It raises a ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. I think that one it's because the questions repeat for each professor. I'm trying to find a way to see if I can bypass that. Wish me luck!

Comment: No, there is only one column for questions and 1 column for the score. The thing is, the questions repeat for each professor. each professor should be represented by a row. The problem is that right now, each question is a row, i.e. q1 has 15 appearances (to give an example) with possibly different scores

Comment: I found out my error for your answer. I had a typo when calling the df when assigning it to k (finals week, what can I say? haha). Thank you so much for your answer! You saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
print(df.groupby('q1').apply(lambda x: x.values[:, 1]).to_frame().T)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I get the same result as using melt. the scores coulmn gets replaced by 2 coulmns: variable and value, all of them with a value of 1 :(

Comment: @LaurySorto Strange, this supposed to work, it does for me